# Jquery expandAll - can't expand by default

Tags: jquery, expand

I'm using expand plugin (http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/expand.html). The problem is that I can't set content as expanded by default.

I used both..

- `$.fn.expandAll.defaults.state = "shown";`
- `$.fn.expandAll.defaults.initTxt = "hide";`

..methods and changing default values directly in the script file:

```
(...)
$.fn.expandAll.defaults = {
state : 'shown', // If 'hidden', the collapsible elements are hidden by default, else they are expanded by default 
initTxt : 'hide', // 'show' - if the initial text of the switch is for expanding, 'hide' - if the initial text of the switch is for collapsing
(...)
```

..but it doesn't work and the content is still hidden. I found a fiddle with a similar issue: **http://jsfiddle.net/wLEGS/22/**.

I would be grateful for any tips how could I solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("your_selector").expandAll('shown');` gets the job done.

```
$(function () {
    $(your_selector_to_expand).expandAll('shown');
});
```

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/wLEGS/23/

Comment: In my eyes is this a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's rather a workaround than a solution but it works. I don't know whether I should mark it as an answer or not.